# How to change music volume in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This is my code, I want to add the volume controller in this code. This code is embedded in Microsoft Sway. It is from Sound Cloud.

```html
<iframe width="1%" height="1" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/590509653&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=true&hide_related=false&show_comments=false&show_user=false&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false&visual=false"></iframe><div style="font-size: 1px; color: #cccccc;line-break: anywhere;word-break: normal;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis; font-family: Interstate,Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Sans,Garuda,Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif;font-weight: 1;"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/joakimkarud" title="  " target="_blank" style="color: #cccccc; text-decoration: none;">  </a> · <a href="https://soundcloud.com/joakimkarud/harmony" title="  " target="_blank" style="color: #cccccc; text-decoration: none;">  </a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `setVolume()` method - `HTMLIFrameElement`. And you can do it with this example:

html

```
<script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
<iframe width="1%" height="1" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/482221002%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-ahwqc&color=%23577c5d&inverse=false&auto_play=true&show_user=true"></iframe>
```

js

```
let audio_iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

widget = SC.Widget(audio_iframe);
widget.setVolume(0.9);
```

You can read the description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/setVolume).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding. Can you show me this in code? Please.

Comment: @snap_potion, do you want to see an example with the `audio` or `iframe` tag?

Comment: iFrame, please use my code as an example.

Comment: This is not only *not supported by some browsers*, it is not supported by any browser in web scripts. It's only supported in Firefox chrome:// code (i.e in extensions), (and it requires the iframe has the `mozbrowser` attribute). Better just forget about this oddity.

Comment: Why do you not recommend using the correct API? Using an audio tag is not possible in OP's case (SoundCloud). The last edit is what this answer should be, only this. Could you remove everything before `html`?

Comment: @Kaiido, why are you closing this question and linking to an answer similar to my answer?

Comment: Because this question is a duplicate of that question. We don't spread answers all around. Besides your answer is still wrong despite my comments. The setVolume your code is using is not the one of the HTMLIFrameElement